# How to display cryptocurrencies on a website

Tags: web3js

I am making a website to practice a bit, on this site, a user connects with metamask, and shows you the coins that you have added in the wallet on the screen.

If you have ETH, it shows you ETH and the amount.

How can I do this last part?

I already made all the connection with metamask and the error capture, but I do not know with what I can do the part of showing different cryptocurrencies and the amount that the user has at his disposal.

I am using web3

For example, on the Cryptomines website, it shows you how much ETERNAL you have in your metamask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You are basically asking for a tutorial on how to build a web3 interface. Try to focus your question on a specific aspect where you have difficulty.

Comment: I just want to know the way to show my amount of cryptocurrencies in metamask on the web